# SwiftUI List section background with rounded corners

Tags: ios, swiftui

I need List section background with custom rounded corners. Trying:

```
            Section {
             ForEach(0..<viewModel.items.count, id:\.self) { index in
               ...
             }   
            }
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            .background(
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .cornerRadius(radius: 45, corners: [.allCorners])
            )
```

But it round corners on every single cell. I need to set background with rounded corners for whole section.

Comment: Section is not a view, it is rather wrapping container (like a Group), so there is nothing in view hierarchy to render your common background. If group List style does not fit your needs then you need to do that manually in ScrollView.

Comment: I need List editable functionality, this is why I am trying to use list with custom section background